# Visual studio image loading in for cycle from resources

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resources, picturebox, filepath

In my image resources I have pictures with following names: c1.png, c2.png, c3.png, ...
Whereas referring to the first image works with `My.Resources.c1`

I would like to display them in the cycle like this

```
        For i = 1 To numberOfPictures
            Dim tmpPicture As New PictureBox

            tmpPicture.Image = cstr(My.Resources.c) & cstr(i) & ".png"
        next
```

Now this of course doesn't work, because string cannot be converted to System.Drawing.Image.
Any ideas how to solve this? I know it's really easy in VB where I did it like this:

```
        For i = 1 To numberOfPictures
            imgName.Picture = loadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\picturesfolder\" & CStr(i) & ".png")
        next i
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767755/how-do-you-load-an-image-from-resource-file-in-vb-2010-expresss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that like this:

```
tmpPicture.Image = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("c" & CStr(i) & ".png"), Bitmap)
```

Here's a hint.  Sometimes it's very useful to look at the designer code.  If you right-click on `My.Resources.c1` and choose the **Go to Definition** option, you'll see the code that is actually executed when you access that property.  The `c1` property is, obviously, not built in as part of the .NET framework.  It's an auto-generated property in a Designer file.  The Resources designer screen automatically generates that code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the images you'd like to cycle into a collection, then you can do a for loop on the collection.

It will look something like this:

```
Dim bmpCol As New Collection(Of Bitmap)
bmpCol.Add(My.Resources.c1)
bmpCol.Add(My.Resources.c2)
'etc
Dim doCycle As Boolean = True
While doCycle
    For Each bmp As Bitmap In bmpCol
        tmpPicture.Image = bmp
    Next
End While
```

You can define the collection globally and add the images to it in the constructor.

You could also have a look on the My.Resources.ResourceManager. Currently i'm not sure if it provides the desired functionality...

**Edit: Well, see *Steven Doggart* post for *that* answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    For i = 1 To numberOfPictures
        Dim tmpPicture As New PictureBox
        Dim objImage = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("c" & i), Bitmap)
        tmpPicture.Image = objImage
    Next
```

It's pretty self-explanatory, but basically, you're just using the `GetObject` method of the `ResourceManager` singleton instance to return the resource you specify dynamically at runtime rather than referencing them how you would normally by their static references (e.g. `My.Resources.c1`) at design time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven's terrific answer I was able to figure out the C# usage

```
tmpPicture.Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("c" & i.toString());
```

although my image was an icon and actual code that worked was

```
_image = (System.Drawing.Icon)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Type + imageNo.toString());
```

Please up vote Stevens answer(they wont let me yet).  That kind of answer is helpful to those who desperately need a quick answer AND for those who want to learn coding.