# Generating procedural imageboxes with textboxes/labels to display text under them

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, procedural

Hey ive got some code that pulls information from a xml file and returns it as strings. im trying to figure out how to take all the blocknames in the xml file and generate an imagebox with a preselected image for each generated box. Heres the code i have.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public FILENAME As String = String.Empty
    Public models As Model
    Public productionBlocks As New Panel
    Public pictureBlocks As New List(Of PictureBox)
    Public gridsinfo As CubeGrid

    Public dictCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Public dictionay As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public fileloader As New OpenFileDialog

    Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = 0

    Const MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = 1000
    Const MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 1000
    Const MAIN_PANEL_TOP As Integer = 50
    Const MAIN_PANEL_LEFT As Integer = 50

    Const PANEL_COLUMNS As Integer = 5
    Const PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN As Integer = 10
    Const PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN As Integer = 10

    Const PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH / PANEL_COLUMNS) - PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN

    Dim PANEL_ROWS As Integer = 0
    Dim PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN As Integer = 0

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
    Const PICTURE_BOX_TOP As Integer = 0
    Const PICTURE_BOX_LEFT As Integer = 0

    Dim LABEL_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim LABEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
    Dim LABEL_TOP As Integer = 0
    Dim LABEL_LEFT As Int16 = 0

    Dim IMAGE_PATH As String = "E:\VS Projects\Resources\SE\Cubes\ArmorCenter.jpg"

    Public _model As Model
    Public mainPanel As New CubeGrid
    Public subPanels As New List(Of CubeBlock)


    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

    Sub CalulateControlSizes(numberOfPanels As Integer)
        PANEL_ROWS = Math.Ceiling(NUMBER_OF_PANELS / PANEL_COLUMNS)
        'PANEL_HEIGHT = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN
        PANEL_HEIGHT = 200

        PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT = 0.8 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        LABEL_HEIGHT = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT
        LABEL_TOP = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

    End Sub




    'FindWords Function to get count of items
    Private Function FindWords(ByVal TextSearched As String, ByVal Paragraph As String) As Integer
        Dim location As Integer = 0
        Dim occurances As Integer = 0

        Do
            location = TextSearched.IndexOf(Paragraph, location)
            If location <> -1 Then
                occurances += 1
                location += Paragraph.Length
            End If
        Loop Until location = -1
        Return occurances
    End Function


    'Open Button
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        'Resetting the list box when new file is loaded
        Try
            For Each item In ListBox1.Items
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'pre-load initialization
        fileloader.ShowDialog()
        FILENAME = fileloader.FileName
        models = New Model
        models.Load(FILENAME)

        'Grabbing information from XML file
        Dim blockNames As List(Of String) = models.print.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(z) z.SubtypeName)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToList()).FirstOrDefault()
        dictCount = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count)
        Dim display As String = models.print2.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.displayname)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).FirstOrDefault.ToString
        Dim gridsizeenum As String = models.print3.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.enumerator)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).FirstOrDefault.ToString
        'Dim ownername As String = models.print4.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.ownername)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).FirstOrDefault.ToString

        'Load items into the listbox
        For Each item In dictCount
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString)
        Next item

        'a useless dictionary method [UN-USED]
        For Each key As String In dictCount.Keys.AsEnumerable()
            Dim keylist As String = "subTypeName = '{0}', count = '{1}'" + key.ToString + dictCount(key).ToString
        Next key

        'Load Text from XML to the read only boxes
        InfluenceTextBox2.Text = "Grid Name: " + display.ToString
        InfluenceTextBox3.Text = "Grid Type: " + gridsizeenum.ToString + " Ship"
        'InfluenceTextBox1.Text = "Owner Name: " + ownername.ToString



        'Gui Displaying
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim xmlstring As String = doc.ToString

        LightArmorBlockText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorBlock").ToString
        LightArmorSlopeText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorSlope").ToString
        LightArmorCornerText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorCorner").ToString
        LightArmorCornerInvertedText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorInvCorner").ToString



        'Function to calculate oxygentanks and hydrogen tanks
        Dim tanks As Integer = FindWords(xmlstring, "MyObjectBuilder_OxygenTank").ToString
        Dim oxygentanks As Integer = tanks - FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeHydrogenTank").ToString
        OxygenTanksText.Text = "Qty: " + oxygentanks.ToString
        HydrogenTanksText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeHydrogenTank").ToString





        dictionay = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Key)
        'Procedural Control Generation

        _model = New Model()
        _model.Load(FILENAME)

        NUMBER_OF_PANELS = _model.print.cubes(0).cubeBlocks.Count
        CalulateControlSizes(NUMBER_OF_PANELS)

        mainPanel = _model.print.cubes(0)
        mainPanel.Height = MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT
        mainPanel.Width = MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH
        mainPanel.Top = MAIN_PANEL_TOP
        mainPanel.Left = MAIN_PANEL_LEFT
        mainPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
        mainPanel.ForeColor = Color.White

        mainPanel.AutoScroll = True
        mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = True
        mainPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = True
        Me.Controls.Add(mainPanel)

        For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)
            Dim row As Integer = Math.Floor(panelNumber / PANEL_COLUMNS)
            Dim col As Integer = panelNumber Mod PANEL_COLUMNS

            Dim newPanel As CubeBlock = _model.print.cubes(0).cubeBlocks(panelNumber)
            newPanel.Top = row * (PANEL_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Left = col * (PANEL_WIDTH + PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Width = PANEL_WIDTH
            newPanel.Height = PANEL_HEIGHT
            newPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
            newPanel.ForeColor = Color.White
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)

            subPanels.Add(newPanel)

            Dim newPicture As New PictureBox()
            newPicture.Height = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT
            newPicture.Width = PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH
            newPicture.Top = PICTURE_BOX_TOP
            newPicture.Left = PICTURE_BOX_LEFT
            newPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(IMAGE_PATH)
            newPicture.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
            newPanel.Controls.Add(newPicture)

            Dim newLabel As New Label
            newLabel.Height = LABEL_HEIGHT
            newLabel.Width = LABEL_WIDTH
            newLabel.Top = LABEL_TOP
            newLabel.Left = LABEL_LEFT
            newLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            newLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
            newLabel.Text = newPanel.SubtypeName & "(" & newPanel.count & ")"
            newLabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            newLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText

            newPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel)

        Next panelNumber
    End Sub
    'END OPEN BUTTON


    'Contributors Section
    Private Sub InfluenceTopButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InfluenceTopButton1.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub


    'XML INPUT LOADING FUNCTION
End Class
Public Class Model
    Public print As New List(Of Model)
    Public print2 As New List(Of Model)
    Public print3 As New List(Of Model)
    Public print4 As New List(Of Model)
    Public _type As String
    Public _id As ID
    Public _display As String
    Public _display1 As String
    Public displayname As String
    Public enumerator As String
    Public cubes As List(Of CubeGrid)
    Public info As String
    Public Sub Load(filename As String)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim firstNode As XElement = doc.FirstNode
        Dim xsiNs = firstNode.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")
        Dim drawingTypes = firstNode.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingType = drawingTypes.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingStr = drawingType.Name.LocalName
        print = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
           ._type = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), ._id = x.Elements("Id").Select(Function(y) New ID() With {
                                              .type = y.Attribute("Type"),
                                              .subtype = y.Attribute("Subtype")
                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
           .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                                                      .id = y.Element("EntityId"),
                                                      .persistentFlags = y.Element("PersistentFlags"),
                                                      .position = y.Descendants("Position").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .forward = y.Descendants("Forward").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .up = y.Descendants("Up").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .orientation = y.Descendants("Orientation").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .w = CType(z.Element("W"), Double),
                                                        .x = CType(z.Element("X"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Element("Y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Element("Z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String)).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Key,
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).OrderBy(Function(z) z.SubtypeName).ToList()
                                                  }).ToList()
        }).ToList()



        print2 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .displayname = y.Element("DisplayName")
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()

        print3 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
        .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
            .enumerator = y.Element("GridSizeEnum")
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()

        'Not Working - Gets owner name
        print4 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            .cubes = x.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_ShipBlueprintDefinition").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .ownername = y.Element("DisplayName")
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ID
    Public type As String
    Public subtype As String
End Class
Public Class CubeGrid
    Inherits Panel

    Public id As String
    Public persistentFlags As String
    Public position As location
    Public forward As location
    Public up As location
    Public orientation As location
    Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)

    Public displayname As String
    Public ownername As String
    Public enumerator As String
End Class
Public Class location
    Public w As Double
    Public x As Double
    Public y As Double
    Public z As Double
End Class
Public Class CubeBlock
    Inherits Panel

    Public SubtypeName As String
    Public username As String
    Public count As Integer
End Class
```

Using the each item in block name create a picture box and a textbox under it < https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQp9T.jpg > For reference.

Creating the custom control using these two generated items as subcontrols:

```
    'Procedural Control Generation
    For Each item In dictCount
        For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)

            Dim row As Integer = Math.Floor(panelNumber / PANEL_COLUMNS)
            Dim col As Integer = panelNumber Mod PANEL_COLUMNS

            Dim newPanel As New Panel
            newPanel.Top = row * (PANEL_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Left = col * (PANEL_WIDTH + PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Width = PANEL_WIDTH
            newPanel.Height = PANEL_HEIGHT
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)
            subPanels.Add(newPanel)

            Dim newTextBox As New TextImagePanelLibrary.TextImagePanel
            newTextBox.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.heavy_armor_cube
            newTextBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
            newTextBox.Height = 100
            newTextBox.Width = 100
            newTextBox.Top = TEXT_BOX_TOP
            newTextBox.Left = TEXT_BOX_LEFT
            newTextBox.Text = "Qty: " + item.ToString



            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newTextBox)
        Next panelNumber
    Next item
```

Getting each item to generate using information from the each item function Item being a string of information containing block name and count

Comment: Please do not write programming languages/libraries/APIs/etc. in the question title apart from [certain situations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208). Otherwise all such things belong in the "Tags" section.

Comment: That's quite some amount of code you've got there. Please try to narrow it down so it is just enough for us to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for what you say you need, I think a [**`FlowLayoutPanel`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) could come in handy.

Comment: Ok i made it minimilistic as much as i could using only what the procedural generation would use

Comment: @VisualVincent Can you please elaborate what you mean i searched this topic for 20 mins and found nothing about it, this is a specific question relating to a specific solution of code.

Comment: A `FlowLayoutPanel` is used to automatically position its sub-controls when you add new ones or resize the control itself. It will position the controls from left to right or top to bottom (depending on your settings), and once it has filled a row or column it will put the next control in a new row/column.

Comment: `this is a specific question relating to a specific solution of code` - Which question doesn't? ;)

Comment: Here's a little tutorial on `FlowLayoutPanels`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w7ek2f(v=vs.110).aspx -- To keep the `PictureBox` and `TextBox` together you can create a custom control cotaining those two controls (i.e. a `UserControl`).

Comment: You can combine cubeblocks using following :                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String)).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With { _
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Key,
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).ToList()
 And adding count to CubeBlock

Comment: Thank you guys for all your input i have everything working 100% except i couldnt get a imagebox with a label right under it like a caption to work properly but my workaround was to create a textbox make it transparent and fix it to the imgboxes which works for now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the syntax errors from your code and simplified soome of the queries.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Public FILENAME As String = String.Empty
    Public models As Model
    Public productionBlocks As New Panel
    Public pictureBlocks As New List(Of PictureBox)
    Public gridsinfo As CubeGrid

    Public dictCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Public dictionay As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public fileloader As New OpenFileDialog

    Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = 0

    Const MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = 1000
    Const MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 1000
    Const MAIN_PANEL_TOP As Integer = 50
    Const MAIN_PANEL_LEFT As Integer = 50

    Const PANEL_COLUMNS As Integer = 5
    Const PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN As Integer = 10
    Const PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN As Integer = 10

    Const PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH / PANEL_COLUMNS) - PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN

    Dim PANEL_ROWS As Integer = 0
    Dim PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN As Integer = 0

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
    Const PICTURE_BOX_TOP As Integer = 0
    Const PICTURE_BOX_LEFT As Integer = 0

    Dim LABEL_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim LABEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
    Dim LABEL_TOP As Integer = 0
    Dim LABEL_LEFT As Int16 = 0

    Dim IMAGE_PATH As String = "c:\temp\image1.jpg"

    Public _model As Model
    Public mainPanel As New CubeGrid
    Public subPanels As New List(Of CubeBlock)


    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

    Sub CalulateControlSizes(numberOfPanels As Integer)
        PANEL_ROWS = Math.Ceiling(NUMBER_OF_PANELS / PANEL_COLUMNS)
        'PANEL_HEIGHT = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN
        PANEL_HEIGHT = 200

        PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT = 0.8 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        LABEL_HEIGHT = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT
        LABEL_TOP = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

    End Sub




    'FindWords Function to get count of items
    Private Function FindWords(ByVal TextSearched As String, ByVal Paragraph As String) As Integer
        Dim location As Integer = 0
        Dim occurances As Integer = 0

        Do
            location = TextSearched.IndexOf(Paragraph, location)
            If location <> -1 Then
                occurances += 1
                location += Paragraph.Length
            End If
        Loop Until location = -1
        Return occurances
    End Function


    'Open Button
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        'Resetting the list box when new file is loaded
        Try
            For Each item In ListBox1.Items
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'pre-load initialization
        fileloader.ShowDialog()
        FILENAME = fileloader.FileName
        models = New Model
        models.Load(FILENAME)

        'Grabbing information from XML file
        Dim blockNames As List(Of String) = models.print.cubes.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(x) x.SubtypeName).ToList()
        dictCount = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count)
        Dim display As String = models.print2.cubes.displayname
        Dim gridsizeenum As String = models.print3.cubes.enumerator
        'Dim ownername As String = models.print4.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.ownername)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).FirstOrDefault.ToString

        'Load items into the listbox
        For Each item In dictCount
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString)
        Next item

        'a useless dictionary method [UN-USED]
        For Each key As String In dictCount.Keys.AsEnumerable()
            Dim keylist As String = "subTypeName = '{0}', count = '{1}'" + key.ToString + dictCount(key).ToString
        Next key

        'Load Text from XML to the read only boxes
        InfluenceTextBox2.Text = "Grid Name: " + display.ToString
        InfluenceTextBox3.Text = "Grid Type: " + gridsizeenum.ToString + " Ship"
        'InfluenceTextBox1.Text = "Owner Name: " + ownername.ToString



        'Gui Displaying
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim xmlstring As String = doc.ToString

        LightArmorBlockText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorBlock").ToString
        LightArmorSlopeText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorSlope").ToString
        LightArmorCornerText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorCorner").ToString
        LightArmorCornerInvertedText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeBlockArmorInvCorner").ToString



        'Function to calculate oxygentanks and hydrogen tanks
        Dim tanks As Integer = FindWords(xmlstring, "MyObjectBuilder_OxygenTank").ToString
        Dim oxygentanks As Integer = tanks - FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeHydrogenTank").ToString
        OxygenTanksText.Text = "Qty: " + oxygentanks.ToString
        HydrogenTanksText.Text = "Qty: " + FindWords(xmlstring, "LargeHydrogenTank").ToString





        dictionay = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Key)
        'Procedural Control Generation

        _model = New Model()
        _model.Load(FILENAME)

        NUMBER_OF_PANELS = _model.print.cubes.cubeBlocks.Count
        CalulateControlSizes(NUMBER_OF_PANELS)

        mainPanel = _model.print.cubes
        mainPanel.Height = MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT
        mainPanel.Width = MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH
        mainPanel.Top = MAIN_PANEL_TOP
        mainPanel.Left = MAIN_PANEL_LEFT
        mainPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
        mainPanel.ForeColor = Color.White

        mainPanel.AutoScroll = True
        mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = True
        mainPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = True
        Me.Controls.Add(mainPanel)

        For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)
            Dim row As Integer = Math.Floor(panelNumber / PANEL_COLUMNS)
            Dim col As Integer = panelNumber Mod PANEL_COLUMNS

            Dim newPanel As CubeBlock = _model.print.cubes.cubeBlocks(panelNumber)
            newPanel.Top = row * (PANEL_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Left = col * (PANEL_WIDTH + PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Width = PANEL_WIDTH
            newPanel.Height = PANEL_HEIGHT
            newPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
            newPanel.ForeColor = Color.White
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)

            subPanels.Add(newPanel)

            Dim newPicture As New PictureBox()
            newPicture.Height = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT
            newPicture.Width = PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH
            newPicture.Top = PICTURE_BOX_TOP
            newPicture.Left = PICTURE_BOX_LEFT
            newPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(IMAGE_PATH)
            newPicture.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 24, 24)
            newPanel.Controls.Add(newPicture)

            Dim newLabel As New Label
            newLabel.Height = LABEL_HEIGHT
            newLabel.Width = LABEL_WIDTH
            newLabel.Top = LABEL_TOP
            newLabel.Left = LABEL_LEFT
            newLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            newLabel.ForeColor = Color.White
            newLabel.Text = newPanel.SubtypeName & "(" & newPanel.count & ")"
            newLabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            newLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText

            newPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel)

        Next panelNumber
    End Sub
    'END OPEN BUTTON


    'Contributors Section
    Private Sub InfluenceTopButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InfluenceTopButton1.Click
        'Form2.Show()
    End Sub


    'XML INPUT LOADING FUNCTION
End Class
Public Class Model
    Public print As Model
    Public print2 As Model
    Public print3 As Model
    Public print4 As Model
    Public _type As String
    Public _id As ID
    Public _display As String
    Public _display1 As String
    Public displayname As String
    Public enumerator As String
    Public cubes As New CubeGrid
    Public info As String
    Public Sub Load(filename As String)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
        Dim firstNode As XElement = doc.FirstNode
        Dim xsiNs = firstNode.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")
        Dim drawingTypes = firstNode.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingType = drawingTypes.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
        Dim drawingStr = drawingType.Name.LocalName
        print = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
           ._type = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), ._id = x.Elements("Id").Select(Function(y) New ID() With {
                                              .type = y.Attribute("Type"),
                                              .subtype = y.Attribute("Subtype")
                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
           .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                                                      .id = y.Element("EntityId"),
                                                      .persistentFlags = y.Element("PersistentFlags"),
                                                      .position = y.Descendants("Position").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .forward = y.Descendants("Forward").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .up = y.Descendants("Up").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .orientation = y.Descendants("Orientation").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                        .w = CType(z.Element("W"), Double),
                                                        .x = CType(z.Element("X"), Double),
                                                        .y = CType(z.Element("Y"), Double),
                                                        .z = CType(z.Element("Z"), Double)
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String)).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Key,
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).OrderBy(Function(z) z.SubtypeName).ToList()
                                                  }).FirstOrDefault()
        }).FirstOrDefault



        print2 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .displayname = y.Element("DisplayName")
            }).FirstOrDefault
        }).FirstOrDefault()

        print3 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
        .cubes = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
            .enumerator = y.Element("GridSizeEnum")
            }).FirstOrDefault
        }).FirstOrDefault

        'Not Working - Gets owner name
        print4 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            .cubes = x.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_ShipBlueprintDefinition").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .ownername = y.Element("DisplayName")
            }).FirstOrDefault
        }).FirstOrDefault
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ID
    Public type As String
    Public subtype As String
End Class
Public Class CubeGrid
    Inherits Panel

    Public id As String
    Public persistentFlags As String
    Public position As location
    Public forward As location
    Public up As location
    Public orientation As location
    Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)

    Public displayname As String
    Public ownername As String
    Public enumerator As String
End Class
Public Class location
    Public w As Double
    Public x As Double
    Public y As Double
    Public z As Double
End Class
Public Class CubeBlock
    Inherits Panel

    Public SubtypeName As String
    Public username As String
    Public count As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: dictCount = blockNames.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count) | Returns each blocktype with a count of 1 instead of actual count

Comment: & i want to do something like "newPicture.Image = My.Resources.(blockname)" this for each image to get a image in my.resources but my.resources.blockname doesnt exactly work properly so any idea how to implement this & also how am i to grab the author of the bp its under DisplayName = author name, the displayname we have currently is the ship name which is under ID

Comment: dictCount = models.print.cubes.cubeBlocks.GroupBy(Function(x) x).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.Count)

Comment: See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353030/visual-studio-image-loading-in-for-cycle-from-resources

Comment: Alright thats done but the pictures and labels dont line up causing a ui bug http://imgur.com/a/Z3Zoa

Comment: Look at CalculateControlSizes.  To get vertical scroll bar to work I commented out PANEL_HEIGHT and made fix value.  The horizontal scroll bar has same issue.  Make PANEL_WIDTH a fix value.  The issue with the alignment is just a wrapping issue with the sizes of the Main_Panel and subpanels.

Comment: You can instead of above reduce the number of columns : PANEL_COLUMNS.  You reduced the MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH from 2000 to 1000 which made the sizes look wrong.  Nothing wrong with changing my initial constants.  I used constants expecting some changes were going to be needed.

Comment: Another trick : I have Public subPanels As New List(Of CubeBlock).  So you can enumerate through subPanels to get block names and count to create your dictionary.

Comment: If you can also post the designer.cs it would make it easier for me to look at results.

Comment: [Designer, https://pastebin.com/m131pPHR ] [Form 1, https://pastebin.com/Pqm3zHv7 ]

Comment: also there is a smidge of problem with the xml parsing, some blocks like Oxygen Tank dont use a subtype name at all and are only referenced by "MyObjectBuilder_OxygenTank" but Hydrogen tanks are also referenced by "MyObjectBuilder_OxygenTank" but use the subtype name LargeHydrogenTank so if you pull "MyObjectBuilder_OxygenTank" you get both of them and without you get only 1

Comment: You can group by both username and subtype :   .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) New With {Key .subName = CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String), Key .userName = CType(z.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), String)}).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
              .SubtypeName = CType(z.FirstOrDefault().Element("SubtypeName"), String),
                                                         .username = z.FirstOrDefault().Attribute(xsiNs + "type"),
                                                        .count = z.Count

Comment: Make sure you paste it into your code so it looks like original code.   You probably are missing a comma so place.

Comment: The Layout Panel has limited properties and I usually find that I need to use a regular Panel to get all the required properties.  The is why I didn't suggest the Layout Panel.

Comment: Code you sent me still had it included.  With the new grouping you should have 87 blocks instead of 81.  I was always wondering where the blank ones were coming from and never had time to find them.

Comment: so can you fix it and send me the fix?

Comment: So how can we get the count of all the blocks in the blueprint to get a total block count

Comment: The GroupBy will give the total counts.  The GroupBy produces a two dimensional array with the groups being the long dimension in the array array and the items in each group being the short dimension in the array

Comment: ok so dim blockcount = models.print.groupby(cubeblocks.count)?

Comment: One of these two methods :  1) Dim total As Integer = subPanels.Select(Function(x) x.count).Sum()
        2) Dim total1 = models.print.cubes.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(x) x.count).Sum()

Answer (score 0):

Try following as a start

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Form1
    Const NUMBER_OF_PANELS = 22

    Const MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = 1000
    Const MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 400
    Const MAIN_PANEL_TOP As Integer = 50
    Const MAIN_PANEL_LEFT As Integer = 50

    Const PANEL_COLUMNS As Integer = 5
    Const PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN As Integer = 10
    Const PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN As Integer = 10

    Const PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH / PANEL_COLUMNS) - PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN

    Dim PANEL_ROWS As Integer = Math.Ceiling(NUMBER_OF_PANELS / PANEL_COLUMNS)
    Dim PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN As Integer = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT

    Dim PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT As Integer = 0.5 * PANEL_HEIGHT
    Const PICTURE_BOX_TOP As Integer = 0
    Const PICTURE_BOX_LEFT As Integer = 0

    Dim TEXT_BOX_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
    Dim TEXT_BOX_HEIGHT As Integer = 0.4 * PANEL_HEIGHT
    Dim TEXT_BOX_TOP As Integer = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN
    Dim TEXT_BOX_LEFT As Int16 = 0

    Dim IMAGE_PATH As String = "c:\temp\image1.jpg"

    Public mainPanel As New Panel
    Public subPanels As New List(Of Panel)
    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Form1_Load

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CalulateControlSizes(NUMBER_OF_PANELS)

        mainPanel = New Panel
        mainPanel.Height = MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT
        mainPanel.Width = MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH
        mainPanel.Top = MAIN_PANEL_TOP
        mainPanel.Left = MAIN_PANEL_LEFT
        Me.Controls.Add(mainPanel)

        For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)
            Dim row As Integer = Math.Floor(panelNumber / PANEL_COLUMNS)
            Dim col As Integer = panelNumber Mod PANEL_COLUMNS

            Dim newPanel As New Panel
            newPanel.Top = row * (PANEL_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Left = col * (PANEL_WIDTH + PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN)
            newPanel.Width = PANEL_WIDTH
            newPanel.Height = PANEL_HEIGHT
            mainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)
            subPanels.Add(newPanel)

            Dim newPicture As New PictureBox()
            newPicture.Height = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT
            newPicture.Width = PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH
            newPicture.Top = PICTURE_BOX_TOP
            newPicture.Left = PICTURE_BOX_LEFT
            newPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(IMAGE_PATH)
            newPanel.Controls.Add(newPicture)

            Dim newTextBox As New TextBox
            newTextBox.Height = TEXT_BOX_HEIGHT
            newTextBox.Width = TEXT_BOX_WIDTH
            newTextBox.Top = TEXT_BOX_TOP
            newTextBox.Left = TEXT_BOX_LEFT
            newTextBox.Text = "PANEL NUMBER" + panelNumber.ToString()
            newTextBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
            newTextBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText

            newPanel.Controls.Add(newTextBox)

        Next panelNumber


    End Sub
    Sub CalulateControlSizes(numberOfPanels As Integer)
        PANEL_ROWS = Math.Ceiling(NUMBER_OF_PANELS / PANEL_COLUMNS)
        PANEL_HEIGHT = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

        PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT = 0.5 * PANEL_HEIGHT

        TEXT_BOX_HEIGHT = 0.4 * PANEL_HEIGHT
        TEXT_BOX_TOP = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Alright how would i go about creating the composite control with a textbox and a image box dockedt to each other

Comment: `Form1_Load` will be called twice. You should remove the `AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Form1_Load` call from the constructor and just keep the `Handles Me.Load` clause.

Comment: First I would change textbox to a label which is more like you image posted on previous posting.  There are already docked since they are both children of a subpanel.  When you move the subpanel both the textbox and image will move together.

Comment: Ok so i want to make some changes to a few things in the xml grabbing

Comment: <Id Type="MyObjectBuilder_ShipBlueprintDefinition" Subtype="BTL.SSD-Retribution" />
      <DisplayName>InaliTsusasi</DisplayName> "Ship name is subtype and the display name is the username that made the blueprint, currently the displayname is being called as the ship name instead of the actual display name"\

Comment: i figured maybe "Dim ownername As String = models.print._id.subtype" but it returns the same value as displayname even tho the ship name is in Subtype of ShipBlueprintDefinition

Comment: I also managed to discern both owner and bp name working correctly now i just need to pull the xsi:type data which im having trouble with [code]._btype = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"),'THIS FUNCTION CURRENTLY RETURNS THE VALUE OF THE BASE XSI Branch MyObjectBuilder_ShipBlueprint but is needed to return the type of the cubeblock that is being currently accessed[/code]

Comment: It will take me a while to get up to speed.  Need to find the xml file.  Not sure what you mean by [code]._btype.  I don't see bytpe in posted code.

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting to for you to understand the 2 projects before combining them.  Now the fun begins with a few easy steps

1) First read the xml

2) Main Panel is a CubeGrid

```
    Public mainPanel As New CubeGrid
    Public subPanels As New List(Of CubeBlock) [you can eliminate this since it is gridsinfo.cubeBlocks]
    mainPanel = gridsinfo.
```

Make CubeGrid inherit Panel.

```
Public Class CubeGrid
    Inherits Panel
    Public id As String
    Public persistentFlags As String
    Public position As location
    Public forward As location
    Public up As location
    Public orientation As location
    Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)

    Public displayname As String
    Public enumerator As String
End Class
```

3) Cube Block is also a Panel which need to inherit Panel.  It should also have a count

```
Public Class CubeBlock
    Inherits Panel
    Public SubtypeName As String
    Public username As String
    Public count As Integer
End Class
```

4) The number of panels is then Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = gridsinfo.cubeBlocks.Count.  You will get errors because NUMBER_OF_Panels changes from a Const to a Dim.  So you have to change some of the Const to Dim.

5)  Now the for loop gets changed

```
        For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)

            Dim newPanel As CubeBlock = gridsinfo.cubeBlocks(panelNumber)
        Next panelNumber
```

Comment: Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = gridsinfo.cubeBlocks.Count = Null reference exception

Comment: Should i make cubeblocks.count using a dictionary to integer or something, im rly not quite sure

Comment: Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = 0 then set it after reading XML to NUMBER_OF_PANELS = gridsinfo.cubeBlocks.Count.

Comment: Dim PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN = overflow exception

Comment: PANEL_ROWS must be zero.  NUMBER _OF_PANELS still must be zero.  You are not reading the xml before getting to this code.

Comment: these are dims right so i should move them to after the xml is read as well

Comment: 'Procedural Control Generation

        NUMBER_OF_PANELS = gridsinfo.cubeBlocks.Count after the xml is loaded = nullreference

Comment: I just realized you have to recalculate the Control values after you read the xml.  I made new procedure in my code below.

Comment: Should of been code above.  Call CalulateControlSizes() method with number of panels obtained from reading xml.

Comment: Please add all your answers into your code i cannot understand you beating around the bush ive had to rewrite the whole project twice trying to figure out wth you are tyring to get at.

Comment: }).FirstOrDefault
        }).FirstOrDefault() needs to be changed to }).FirstOrDefault
        }).ToList() or it throws makes a compilation error

Comment: & _model.print._cubeGrid is still not a List(Of Model)

Comment: Dim blockNames As List(Of String) = models.print.Select(Function(x) x.cubes.Select(Function(y) y.cubeBlocks.Select(Function(z) z.SubtypeName)).SelectMany(Function(y) y).ToList()).FirstOrDefault() & this is broken  by the change as well

Comment: I just took posted and into a new project and it runs with no errors.  The model is the ShipBluePrint.  If you want a List(Of Model) you would need another xml file.  The List object are in the CubeGrid and are the List(Of CubeBlock).

Comment: So if it works in a different project why isnt it working now

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code

```
    Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Xml.Linq
    Public Class Form1
        Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

        Dim NUMBER_OF_PANELS = 0

        Const MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = 1000
        Const MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 1000
        Const MAIN_PANEL_TOP As Integer = 50
        Const MAIN_PANEL_LEFT As Integer = 50

        Const PANEL_COLUMNS As Integer = 5
        Const PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN As Integer = 10
        Const PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN As Integer = 10

        Const PANEL_WIDTH As Integer = (MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH / PANEL_COLUMNS) - PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN

        Dim PANEL_ROWS As Integer = 0
        Dim PANEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0

        Dim PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN As Integer = 0

        Dim PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
        Dim PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
        Const PICTURE_BOX_TOP As Integer = 0
        Const PICTURE_BOX_LEFT As Integer = 0

        Dim LABEL_WIDTH As Integer = PANEL_WIDTH
        Dim LABEL_HEIGHT As Integer = 0
        Dim LABEL_TOP As Integer = 0
        Dim LABEL_LEFT As Int16 = 0

        Dim IMAGE_PATH As String = "c:\temp\image1.jpg"

        Public _model As Model
        Public mainPanel As New CubeGrid
        Public subPanels As New List(Of CubeBlock)
        Sub New()

            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()

            ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
            AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Form1_Load

        End Sub
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            _model = New Model()
            _model.Load(FILENAME)
            NUMBER_OF_PANELS = _model.print._cubeGrid.cubeBlocks.Count
            CalulateControlSizes(NUMBER_OF_PANELS)

            mainPanel = _model.print._cubeGrid
            mainPanel.Height = MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT
            mainPanel.Width = MAIN_PANEL_WIDTH
            mainPanel.Top = MAIN_PANEL_TOP
            mainPanel.Left = MAIN_PANEL_LEFT

            mainPanel.AutoScroll = True
            mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = True
            mainPanel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(mainPanel)

            For panelNumber As Integer = 0 To (NUMBER_OF_PANELS - 1)
                Dim row As Integer = Math.Floor(panelNumber / PANEL_COLUMNS)
                Dim col As Integer = panelNumber Mod PANEL_COLUMNS

                Dim newPanel As CubeBlock = _model.print._cubeGrid.cubeBlocks(panelNumber)
                newPanel.Top = row * (PANEL_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN)
                newPanel.Left = col * (PANEL_WIDTH + PANEL_WIDTH_MARGIN)
                newPanel.Width = PANEL_WIDTH
                newPanel.Height = PANEL_HEIGHT
                mainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel)
                subPanels.Add(newPanel)

                Dim newPicture As New PictureBox()
                newPicture.Height = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT
                newPicture.Width = PICTURE_BOX_WIDTH
                newPicture.Top = PICTURE_BOX_TOP
                newPicture.Left = PICTURE_BOX_LEFT
                newPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(IMAGE_PATH)
                newPanel.Controls.Add(newPicture)

                Dim newLabel As New Label
                newLabel.Height = LABEL_HEIGHT
                newLabel.Width = LABEL_WIDTH
                newLabel.Top = LABEL_TOP
                newLabel.Left = LABEL_LEFT
                newLabel.Text = newPanel.SubtypeName & "(" & newPanel.count & ")"
                newLabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
                newLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText

                newPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel)

            Next panelNumber


        End Sub
        Sub CalulateControlSizes(numberOfPanels As Integer)
            PANEL_ROWS = Math.Ceiling(NUMBER_OF_PANELS / PANEL_COLUMNS)
            'PANEL_HEIGHT = (MAIN_PANEL_HEIGHT / PANEL_ROWS) - PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN
            PANEL_HEIGHT = 200

            PICTURE_BOX_MARGIN = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT

            PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT = 0.8 * PANEL_HEIGHT

            LABEL_HEIGHT = 0.1 * PANEL_HEIGHT
            LABEL_TOP = PICTURE_BOX_HEIGHT + PANEL_HEIGHT_MARGIN

        End Sub

    End Class
    Public Class Model
        Public print As Model
        Public print2 As Model
        Public print3 As Model

        Public _type As String
        Public _id As ID
        Public _display As String
        Public _display1 As String
        Public displayname As String
        Public enumerator As String
        Public _cubeGrid As CubeGrid
        Public info As String

        Public Sub Load(filename As String)

            Dim reader As New StreamReader(filename)

            Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
            Dim firstNode As XElement = doc.FirstNode
            Dim xsiNs = firstNode.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi")
            Dim drawingTypes = firstNode.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
            Dim drawingType = drawingTypes.Elements.FirstOrDefault()
            Dim drawingStr = drawingType.Name.LocalName

            print = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
               ._type = x.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"),
               ._id = x.Elements("Id").Select(Function(y) New ID() With {
                                                  .type = y.Attribute("Type"),
                                                  .subtype = y.Attribute("Subtype")
                                              }).FirstOrDefault(),
               ._cubeGrid = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                                                          .id = y.Element("EntityId"),
                                                          .persistentFlags = y.Element("PersistentFlags"),
                                                          .position = y.Descendants("Position").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                            .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                            .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                            .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                          .forward = y.Descendants("Forward").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                            .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                            .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                            .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                          .up = y.Descendants("Up").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                            .x = CType(z.Attribute("x"), Double),
                                                            .y = CType(z.Attribute("y"), Double),
                                                            .z = CType(z.Attribute("z"), Double)
                                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                          .orientation = y.Descendants("Orientation").Select(Function(z) New location() With {
                                                            .w = CType(z.Element("W"), Double),
                                                            .x = CType(z.Element("X"), Double),
                                                            .y = CType(z.Element("Y"), Double),
                                                            .z = CType(z.Element("Z"), Double)
                                                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                      .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) New With {Key .subName = CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String), Key .userName = CType(z.Attribute(xsiNs + "type"), String)}).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
                                                        .SubtypeName = CType(z.FirstOrDefault().Element("SubtypeName"), String),
                                                         .username = z.FirstOrDefault().Attribute(xsiNs + "type"),
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).OrderBy(Function(z) z.SubtypeName).ToList()
                                                      }).FirstOrDefault
            }).FirstOrDefault()


            print2 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
                ._cubeGrid = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                    .displayname = y.Element("DisplayName")
                }).FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault()

            print3 = doc.Descendants(drawingStr).Select(Function(x) New Model() With {
            ._cubeGrid = x.Descendants("CubeGrid").Select(Function(y) New CubeGrid() With {
                .enumerator = y.Element("GridSizeEnum")
                }).FirstOrDefault
            }).FirstOrDefault()
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class ID
        Public type As String
        Public subtype As String
    End Class
    Public Class CubeGrid
        Inherits Panel

        Public id As String
        Public persistentFlags As String
        Public gridSizeEnum As String
        Public position As location
        Public forward As location
        Public up As location
        Public orientation As location
        Public cubeBlocks As List(Of CubeBlock)

        Public displayname As String
        Public enumerator As String
    End Class
    Public Class location
        Public w As Double
        Public x As Double
        Public y As Double
        Public z As Double
    End Class
    Public Class CubeBlock
        Inherits Panel
        Public SubtypeName As String
        Public count As Integer
    End Class
```

Comment: I added a scroll bar

Comment: I now ordered the blocks by name

Comment: Cubes is not a member of List(Of Model)

Comment: Dim newPanel As CubeBlock = _model.print.cubes(0).cubeBlocks(panelNumber)

Comment: load function: Value of type model can not be converted to List(Of Model)

Comment: changing your .cubeblocks to > .cubeBlocks = y.Descendants("MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock").GroupBy(Function(z) CType(z.Element("SubtypeName"), String)).Select(Function(z) New CubeBlock() With {
                                                        .SubtypeName = z.Key,
                                                        .count = z.Count
                                                      }).OrderBy(Function(z) z.SubtypeName).ToList()
                                                  }).ToList() Fixes the problem

Comment: but still getting _model.print.cubes(0) cubes is not a member of list(of Model)

Comment: There seems to be issues with upper case and lower case letters between our two versions of Visual Studio.  It should be : _model.print.cubes(0).cubeBlocks.  Cubes is empty because you are using print instead of cubes

Comment: Im not understanding how our versions of vb are having issues

Comment: and that still dont explain why the thing is not a list of models or whatever

Comment: I was just trying to match your classes with the xml.  I can make what ever changes needed.  A CubeBlock is a subpanel.  So I made Main Panel the parent of the class CubeBlocks which was CubeGrid which contains List(Of CubeBlocks),  I can make Main Panel any class that you like as long as it has a property or child property that contains a List(Of CubeBlocks)

Comment: I think what we have is correct.  You have to be able to map the controls with the classes.  The Model is the Main Form.  Then you need a control and class that contains all the sub-panels which is CubeGrid.  This way you can move CubeGrid easily on the form by just changing the top and left properties.  Eliminating CubGrid makes it harder to lock the sub-panels together.

Comment: Thats a good explination but it doesnt help me understand why its saying thats is not in a list(of models) for that line of code i posted

Comment: It really should be Public _cubeGrid as CubeGrid and not  Public cubes As List(Of CubeGrid). We are using the cube property in the CubeGrid instead. We have three levels 1) Form : Model : ShipBlueprint(xml) 2) Main Panel : CubeGrid : CubeGrid(xml) 3) SubPanel : CubeBlock : MyObjectBuilder_CubeBlock(xml)

Comment: your not making much sense lol can you make the changes in yhe code and then show me there?

Comment: Modified code.  If you press the edit button below code it will show old and new code side-by-side

Comment: I updated my code if u can have a look and see if im doing something wrong

Comment: your post contains some code formatting errors please fix